# where to find a singularity definition file in sandbox

Tags: singularity-container

I am trying to learn singularity so I pulled from their library this example:

```
singularity pull library://sylabsed/examples/lolcow
```

After pulling I wanted to check what are the directories inside this image and if there is any definition file that was used to build the image, therefore I went to develop mode by building a `sandbox`:

```
sudo singularity build --sandbox lowcow/ library://sylabsed/examples/lolcow
```

Once I inspected into the directory `lowcow/` I have not found any singularity `.def` definition file.

Could someone please explain to me if it's possible to find the definition file in the `sandbox` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can find the definition file at `/.singularity.d/Singularity`. You do not have to build a sandbox image for this. You can do this directly from the downloaded image.

```
singularity exec library://sylabsed/examples/lolcow cat /.singularity.d/Singularity
```

This is even possible with Docker images:

```
$ singularity exec docker://alpine:3.11 cat /.singularity.d/Singularity
bootstrap: docker
from: alpine:3.11
```