# Singularity can not remove a folder, read-only file system

Tags: singularity-container

I have deployed a image from docker hub into singularity 2.6.0 and run the container as below.

```
singularity run -B ~/path-to-mount/:/home ~/oqfe_latest.sif -1 /home/file_R1.fastq.gz -2 /home/file_R2.fastq.gz --sample sid1
```

while running on the container, the tool downloads a file and unzip it, and then tries to remove the original files, but it could not, and shows the error below:

```
rm -rf /data/GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.tar.gz
rm: cannot remove '/data/GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.tar.gz': Read-only file system
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/oqfe", line 528, in <module>
    args.cram_reference_fasta)
  File "/oqfe", line 486, in main
    bwa_reference_index_path = _setup_reference(DEFAULT_REFERENCE_TAR_PATH)
  File "/oqfe", line 130, in _setup_reference
    _run_cmd(cmd)
  File "/oqfe", line 110, in _run_cmd
    subprocess.check_call(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['rm', '-rf', '/data/GRCh38_full_analysis_set_plus_decoy_hla.tar.gz']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I built the container using option --sandbox,  unfortunately the error still exist.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In order to modify a sandbox, you must use `--writable` with your singularity run/exec/shell command.

Note that to ensure you will have appropriate permissions [the docs recommend running a sandbox as root/with sudo](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.7/user-guide/build_a_container.html?highlight=sandbox#creating-writable-sandbox-directories).

---

As a broader comment, if the data on your image is going to be modified it is generally better to mount it in when the container is run rather than when it is built. I also leave it out when it is particularly large, as with the decoy fasta. The singularity image then simply becomes software, as well as smaller and easier to transfer. This is of course dependent on use case and individual preference, but I find it more convenient.

Comment: Thanks, the image is not mine and I. can't edit it. It contains in itself a data file which uses it for the pipeline process. It does not use the path that I mount for its internal temp file.

Comment: @Ahmad.S Since I stumbled in a problem similar to yours, I would like to add that you can retrieve the def file used to build a singularity image with: `singularity exec oqfe_latest.sif cat /.singularity.d/Singularity`. _Per se_ the image it's not editable except when using `--writable` as tsnowlan points out, but with the def file in principle you can create a variation based on it. (see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272765/where-to-find-a-singularity-definition-file-in-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered exactly the same problem. There are perhaps other more elegant solutions but what I did was to mount a directory to the `/data` directory so that `/data` is writable. Because `/data/` contains a file that is used by the pipeline, I had to copy the file to the directory that will be mounted.

Here are roughly the steps that I used:

```bash
# get into the container
singularity exec --bind /my_data_dir:/data_tmp oqfe_latest.sif /bin/bash

# insider the container, copy the file to /my_data_dir 
cp /data/* /data_tmp

# run the container with "outside" /data
singularity run --bind /my_data_dir:/data oqfe_latest.sif ... # other options
```